# "No package.json files were found in the workspace" error in VSC

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

On Windows 11 PC in Visual Studio Code I:

1. Open Command Palette.
2. Search for "docker" and click Add Docker Files to Workspace.
3. Select Node.js.

Then I get "No package.json files were found in the workspace."

[vsc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21zvi.jpg)

(Docker extension is already installed).

Could you please advise why it is so?

I installed  Node.js application but it didn't help.

Comment: related source code: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/blob/v1.25.1/src/scaffolding/wizard/node/NodeScaffoldingWizardContext.ts#L16 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/blob/v1.25.1/src/scaffolding/wizard/ChooseArtifactStep.ts#L20 so,... does your workspace have a package.json in it? The extension expects there to be one when you select NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

npm init -y

Note:- This command will create a `package.json` file, and you are ready to go!